# Change size of user flair

Tags: feature-request, flair

How can I make User Flair the right size (90x58 pixels) without using HTML? The forum I want to put this on doesn't let me use anything but [img]URL_of_picture_here[/img].
Is there any way to change the size by ONLY changing the URL? And I would like the resized picture updated as my reputation/etc changes.

Thanks.

Comment: In regards to your last sentence, the images automatically update with changes (although it takes some time, due to the fact that it's cached by both server and browser).

Comment: @waiwai933 Yeah, but I meant in my resized image. I added the term "resized" to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one size for official .png image flair at the moment.

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair

However, there are several alternative flair services at http://stackapps.com that are more flexibile -- perhaps one of those would work for you?

https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/flair